# C++ error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++

I wrote the code below to perform few tasks.

Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define MOD 1000000007
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t; cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        long long int N; cin >> N;
        vector<long long int> cars(N);
        for (long long int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            cin >> cars[i];
        }
        sort(cars.begin(), cars.end(), greater<long long int>());

        long long int profit = 0;
        for (long long int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            if (cars[i]) {
                profit += cars[i] - i;
            }
        }

        cout << profit << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I really don't know why I am facing this error while I am submitting the code. Could anyone please help me in getting out of this.
Input
The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.
The second line contains N space-separated integers P1,P2,…,PN.
Output
For each test case, print a single line containing one integer ― the maximum profit Chef can make, modulo 1,000,000,007.

```
Constraints
1≤T≤25
1≤N≤105
0≤Pi≤109 for each valid i

The inputs are 
2 next line
3 next line
6 6 6 next line
3 next line
0 1 0 

Expected Output
15 next line
1
```

Comment: Do you have an example input file?

Comment: What is the value of `N`?

Comment: The code is incorrect as it allows for negative values of `N`, which will definitely trigger an OOM.

Comment: @ArnoDeceuninck The inputs are 2
3
6 6 6
3
0 1 0

Comment: `while (t--)` -- A tell-tale sign that this comes from one of those online judge websites.  What are the possible values of `N`?

Comment: @AndreySemashev but i guess on competitive programming platforms, usually they don't pass such tricky inputs

Comment: *The inputs are 2 next line 3 next line 6 6 6 next line 3 next line 0 1 0* -- You should just assign the variables with these values instead of having to use `cin`.  That way, no one has to sit at their keyboard typing in data over and over again each time they run the program.

Comment: @walidbarakat given the title of the question, it's a reasonable guess such an input occurs

Comment: @Caleth, i agree, but i meant with the fact we have a code run on a platform with inputs meant to measure the way of solution more than anything, and we can see the inputs range. i hope i made myself clear as well.

Comment: Your question still doesn't clear for me , Can you add more details ?! @KanigantiSaiTarun

Answer (score 0):

i tried the inputs from your code, and it seems working fine, you just miss the headers needed here. **vector**, **iostream** and **algorithm**, Maybe There's nothing wrong with your code, you're simply running on a platform likely with small memory limits. you need to focus on optimization, but if you have something wrong with the results you need please to provide the idea behind the code, example of input, expected output, current output and ranges of t and N.

check : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i tried the inputs and it seems works fine, but you miss the header in your code

Comment: @KanigantiSaiTarun No, it's bad practice, don't use that header: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h